Not executing stop loss at desired % in tradingview backtesting
Creating a trading bot with pine script and the code seems to be working for the % take profit but not executing the at the desired stop loss of 2% when backtesting. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!
Here is the snippet:
// Set take profit and stop loss for long positions
    if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    float takeProfitPriceLong = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.03
    float stopLossPriceLong = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.98
    strategy.exit("Take Profit Long", from_entry="Long", limit=takeProfitPriceLong)
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss Long", from_entry="Long", stop=stopLossPriceLong)

// Set take profit and stop loss for short positions
    if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    float takeProfitPriceShort = strategy.position_avg_price * 0.97
    float stopLossPriceShort = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.02
    strategy.exit("Take Profit Short", from_entry="Short", limit=takeProfitPriceShort)
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss Short", from_entry="Short", stop=stopLossPriceShort)`

